# "Permission Denied" using cygwin in Windows

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, file-permissions

***Background:***
I am trying to write a [.bat] file so I can double click it and a bash script will get invoked.  The bash script will start up a few windows GUI apps to monitor GPU/CPU temperatures.  I just did a fresh install of cygwin v1.7.7-1 (downloaded today) and windows 7.

***Code:***
monitor-temps.bat:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe ~/bin/monitor-temps.bash
pause
```

***Code:***
monitor-temps.bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
"/cygdrive/c/Users/michael/Desktop/apps_and_drivers/GPU-Z.0.4.8.exe" &
```

***Output:***
After I double click the [.bat] file, I get a:

```
C:\Users\michael\Desktop>C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe ~/bin/monitor-temps.bash

C:\Users\michael\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . . /home/michael/bin/monitor-temps.bash: line 2: /cygdrive/c/Users/michael/Desktop/apps_and_drivers/GPU-Z.0.4.8.exe: Permission denied
```

I still get the same permissions error when I cd to the directory and manually execute the application.

***Permissions:***
From my experience with permission problems in Linux, everything looks good because I am the user I think I am, and the file has the expected permissions:

```
$ whoami
michael

$ ls -l GPU*
-rwx------+ 1 michael        None 890720 2010-12-01 19:23 GPU-Z.0.4.8.exe
```

***Question:***
Does anyone know how to fix this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

As a Developer, I use a shortcut to provide a command-line interface (CLI) that behaves similar to Linux, in my Windows environment, and ran into the same issue trying to untar a file.

The fix was to set the shortcut to "Run as Administrator".

If you are using this method to access your Cygwin environment, go to the properties of the shortcut, select the Advanced button to get the options to "Run as Administrator", check the box, click Ok. And off you go!!
You can also set your batch file to do this, by making a shortcut to it and doing the above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So much simpler than messing with setfacl, which didn't do the trick for me.  Just shift-right-click on the Cygwin icon, select "Run as Administrator", and suddenly the compile-time folder creation was working!  Thanks, @Darkstrumm!

Comment: I needed to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to fix a profile problem and starting the terminal as administrator was the only thing that would allow me to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: This tip does not work for network drives. "Run as Administrator" mode restricts access to `/cygdrive/c` only.

Comment: This is a dangerous solution: every process that you run will inherit Administrator access, exposing your machine needlessly.  Solve the underlying permissions problem with Windows tools designed for that purpose, do not just "run as root all the time" -- e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587028/237059 (which should be the accepted answer).

Answer (score 13):

I think you have to change the directory or file permission. If you want to change permission of a file or directory then you have to add full path with the code.

As if you want to change permission on cocos2d-x folder on C:\yourDirectory (I'm on Windows; on Mac it would be `/` instead of `\`) write the code on cygwin console:

```
chmod -R 775 /cygwindrive/c/yourDirectory
```

Note: If it's in C: drive you have to run it as administrator.

Comment: This didn't work in C:/ for me. Permission denied, had to run the cygwin console as Administrator.

Comment: Changing permission of the bash file was enough for me.

Answer (score 10):

- Check the mount table with `cat /proc/mounts` or `mount` and make sure that every mount point out of `/`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` has a `noacl` flag.  If it's missing, correct `/etc/fstab` and reboot.  (Rebooting synced up the `noacl` flag of the root mount point for me, and I do not know if the same can be achieved without rebooting).
- Check for a NULL SID record and other strange records in the output of icacls against the file.  They appear added on writing by the POSIX ACL translation layer in Cygwin (using "noacl" in /etc/fstab allows disabling that, but the damage will have already been done).

  Resetting the Windows ACL just on the file may not be enough if the containing parents had the NULL SID record.  One has to run

  ```
  icacls c:\cygwin64 /reset /t /l /c
  ```

  from Command Prompt to remove the extraneous records from the Windows ACL in each file and directory.

**Update**
Other commands reset the ownership, remove default ACLs and show ACLs of a known binary before and after the changes:

```
set croot=c:\cygwin64
icacls %croot%\bin\ls.exe
%croot%\bin\getfacl /bin/ls
takeown /F %croot% /R /D Y > nul
icacls %croot% /reset /T /C /L /Q
icacls %croot%\bin\ls.exe

%croot%\bin\getfacl /bin/setfacl
%croot%\bin\getfacl /bin/find
%croot%\bin\setfacl -bk /bin/find
%croot%\bin\find -P / -xdev -exec /bin/setfacl -bk "{}" +

icacls %croot%\bin\ls.exe
%croot%\bin\getfacl /bin/ls
```

Comment: In addition to the above I figured I needed to remove inherited permissions, setting full access for .\Administrators and .\SYSTEM. I guess this can be scripted with one extra ```icacls %croot% /grant:r SYSTEM:F Administrators:F /t /c /l /q```.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to fix this is:

1. Download [Sysinternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), start it and let it run for a while.
2. Exclude all processes that generate noise.
3. When the log becomes less busy, start your file access attempt.
4. Search the ProcMon log for "Access Denied" messages.
5. Investigate. Should be easy to fix.

Comment: So, what's the fix if it's easy to fix? I found that my .dll that i want to dlopen is returning an access denied message in procmon

Comment: @activedecay You look at the details for that line (double click), find out which process and which user is trying to get access, and then you either modify the file system rights of the DLL, or of the folder the DLL is in, or you change the user the process runs as.

Answer (score 5):

-rwx------+ might be the problem. Some hidden acl may forbid x for you.
Reset your acl with setfacl then.

```
$ cat >/tmp/faclx <<EOF
user::rwx
group::r--
mask:rwx
other:r--
EOF
$ setfacl -f /tmp/faclx /cygdrive/c/Users/michael/Desktop/apps_and_drivers/GPU-Z.0.4.8.exe
```

Or you need elevated permissions:

```
$ cygstart  --action=runas /cygdrive/c/Users/michael/Desktop/apps_and_drivers/GPU-Z.0.4.8.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and fixed it by `cd` to the directory which contains the box I just made (packaged, or, repackaged). Then `vagrant box add <file.box> --name <name>`. I think the PATHs fvck things up, and cause it to fail. Then double check with `vagrant box list`. Then I `mkdir coolbox; cd coolbox`. Then I just `vagrant init <name>` and it all comes up like magic.

Answer (score 0):

git bash, run command like this:  `cmd "/C postgresql-10.5-2-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --servicename 'postgreSQL'"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue around tee redirection:

```
"%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\bash.exe" -c "{ cd ""%PWD:\=/%""; CHERE_INVOKING=. ""%CYGWIN_ROOT:\=/%/bin/bash.exe"" -l -i; } 2>&1 | ""%CYGWIN_ROOT:\=/%/bin/tee.exe"" -a ""%PROJECT_LOG_FILE:\=/%"""
```

This kind of code is required if you want to run a bash shell with login in a specific directory (`cd` before call to login shell).

But in mine case it won't work, because of the error: `tee: 'standard output': Permission denied`

*Update*:

Found a fix here: https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2020-December/247185.html

```
In Win7,
1) Start command prompt.
2) Run chcp 65001
3) Change the font of command prompt to raster font.
4) Run c:\cygwin\bin\printf "\xce\b1\n"

This causes the error:
/usr/bin/printf: write error

What weird is that if the font is other than raster font,
this error does not occur.
```

A raster font triggers the console write error (a `permission denied` in case of piping) under 65001 code page specifically in the Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instruction found in this link: https://cygwin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#install-and-maintain-cygwin
and when it comes to give permissions to the folder on windows use the command:
chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/cyg-get
From the Cygwin Terminal , as in this example:

Open Cygwin64 Terminal, and run:

```
chmod -R 775 /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score -1):

just change the mode of the scripts using chmod command to make it executable.
see man chmod for more details.

Comment: If you're running into windows/cygwin permissions issues, chmod will have no effect.  Trust me, I keep trying it, but my files end up with 755 permissions every time.  Changing security permissions in windows does no good either.