# permission denied when installing python packages through cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I'm working on a windows 7 and using Cygwin for unix-like functionality. I can write and run Python scripts fine from the Cygwin console, and the installation of Python packages using `pip install`is successful and the installed package appears under `pip list`. However, if I try to run a script that imports these packages, for example the 'aloe' package, I get the error "no such module named 'aloe'".

I have discovered that the packages are being installed to c:\python27\lib\site-packages, i.e. the computer's general list of python packages, and not to /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages, i.e. the list of python packages available within Cygwin. I don't know how to rectify this though. If I try to specify the install location using `easy_install-3.6 aloe` I get the error

> `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-7592.write-test'.`

In desperation also tried directly copying the 'aloe' directory to the Cygwin Python packages directory using cmd with `cp -r \python27\lib\site-packages\aloe \cygwin\lib\python3.6\site-packages` and the move was successful, but the problem persists and when I check in the Cygwin console using `ls /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` I can't see 'aloe'.

I have admin rights to the computer in general (`sudo` is not available in Cygwin anyway) so really can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try `pip3 install aloe` inside your cygwin like how you normally install a package, copying python2 package to python3 is not going to work well.

Comment: that gives the same error as easy_install-3.6

Comment: you have admin rights to the PC, just need to confirm are you running cygwin in admin mode?

Comment: does that just mean running it on in an admin account? if so then yes, if not then how may I find out?

Comment: yes I meant that. i.e. right click and select `running as administrator`. looks like cygwin has some weird setup. try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/614237/permission-denied-when-using-mv-in-windows-7-cygwin) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479615/permission-denied-using-cygwin-in-windows).

Comment: ah yes this plus pip3 worked, thank you :)

Comment: I'll put up an answer as well, so if that helps, please give a tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure you are in admin mode.

i.e. right click on Cygwin, select `running as administrator`.

then install your package specifically using pip3, for python3.

i.e. `pip3 install your_package`

with updated version, do `pip3 install --upgrade your_package`

Comment: Or right-click the `DOS cmd` icon and **Run as administrator**.